# The Implications of Modern Day Software Development Abstractions

Tags: language-agnostic, abstraction

I am currently doing a dissertation about the implications or dangers that today's software development practices or teachings may have on the long term effects of programming.

Just to make it clear: **I am not attacking the use abstractions in programming**.  Every programmer knows that abstractions are the bases for modularity.

What I want to investigate with this dissertation are the positive and negative effects abstractions can have in software development.  As regards the positive, I am sure that I can find many sources that can confirm this.  But what about the negative effects of abstractions?  Do you have any stories to share that talk about when certain abstractions failed on you?

The main concern is that many programmers today are programming against abstractions without having the faintest idea of what the abstraction is doing under-the-covers.  This may very well lead to bugs and bad design.  So, in you're opinion, how important is it that programmers actually know what is going below the abstractions?

Taking a simple example from [Joel's Back to Basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html), C's strcat:

```
void strcat( char* dest, char* src )
{
     while (*dest) dest++;
     while (*dest++ = *src++);
}
```

The above function hosts the issue that if you are doing string concatenation, the function is always starting from the beginning of the dest pointer to find the null terminator character, whereas if you write the function as follows, you will return a pointer to where the concatenated string is, which in turn allows you to pass this new pointer to the concatenation function as the *dest parameter:

```
char* mystrcat( char* dest, char* src )
{
     while (*dest) dest++;
     while (*dest++ = *src++);
     return --dest;
}
```

Now this is obviously a very simple as regards abstractions, but it is the same concept I shall be investigating.

Finally, what do you think about the issue that schools are preferring to teach Java instead of C and Lisp ?

Can you please give your opinions and your says as regards this subject?

Thank you for your time and I appreciate every comment.

Comment: I tend to take the position that if an abstraction requires understanding of the underlying mechanisms (as in your example), it's not really an abstraction, it's just syntactic sugar. With that in mind, I'd say the only danger of abstractions is that they aren't really abstractions: that they've got bugs that make their behavior dependent on the underlying mechanisms instead of the abstracted model. Although there is a drawback in that they come with an inherent inefficiency since they are not using the underlying mechanism to the fullest.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, abstractions are inevitable because they help us to deal with the mind-blowing complexity of things.

Abstractions are also inevitable because it is more and more required of an individual to undertake more tasks or even complete projects. To address the problem, one uses libraries which wrap lower-level concepts and expose more complex behavior.

Naturally, a developer has less and less time to know the intrinsics of the things. The latest concern I heard about on SO pages is starting to learn JavaScript with jQuery library, ignoring the raw JavaScript at all.

The issue is about the balance between:

- Know the little tiniest details of some technology and be a master of it, but at the same time being unable to work with anything else.
- Superficial knowledge of a wide variety of technologies and tools which however proves sufficient for common everyday tasks which allows an individual to perform in multiple areas possibly covering all sides of some (moderately big) project.

Take your pick.

Some work requires the one, another position requires the other.

> So, in you're opinion, how important is it that programmers actually know what is going below the abstractions?

It would be nice if people knew what is happening behind the scenes. This knowledge comes with time and practice, up to a certain degree. Depends on what kind of tasks you have. You certainly shouldn't blame people for not knowing everything. If you wish a person to be able to perform in a variety of fields, it is inevitable he won't have time to cover each up to the last bit.

What is essential, is the knowledge of the basic building blocks. Data structures, algorithms, complexity. That should provide a basis for everything else.

Knowing tiniest details of some particular technology is good, but not essential. Anyway, you can't learn them all. They're too many and they keep coming.

> Finally, what do you think about the issue that schools are preferring to teach Java instead of C and Lisp ?

Schools shouldn't be teaching programming languages at all. They're to teach basics of theoretical and practical CS, social skills, communication, team work. To cover a vast variety of topics and problems to provide a wide angle view for their graduates. This will help them to find their way. Whatever they need to know in details, they'll do it on their own.

Answer (score 1):

An example where abstraction has failed:

In this case, a piece of software was needed to communicate to many different third party data processors.  The communication was done through various messaging protocols; the transport method/protocol is not important in this case.  Just assume everyone communicated through messaging.

The idea was to abstract the features of each of these third parties into a single, unified message format.  It seemed relatively straightforward because each of the third parties performed a similar service.  The problem was that some third parties used different terms to explain similar features.  It was also found that some third parties had additional features that other third parties did not have.

The designers of the abstraction did not see through the difference of third party terms nor did they think it was reasonable to limit the scope of the unified features to only support the common features of the third parties.  Instead, a single, monolithic message schema was developed to support any and all features of the third parties considered at the time.  In what was probably considered a future-proofing move, they added a means of also passing an infinite number of name/value pairs along with the monolithic message in case there were future data elements that the monolithic message could not handle.

Early on, it became clear that changing the monolithic message was going to be difficult due to so many people using it in mission critical systems.  The use of the name/value pairs increased. Each name that could be used was documented inside a large spreadsheet, and developers were required to consult the spreadsheet to avoid duplication of name value function.  The list got so large, however, that it was found that there were frequently collisions in purposes of name values.

The majority of the monolithic message's fields now have no purpose and are kept mainly for backwards compatibility.  There are name values that can be used to replace fields in the monolithic message.  The majority of the interfacing is now done through the name/value pairs.  In cases where the client is intending to communicate with more than one third party, each client needs to reconcile the name values available for each third party.  It would be almost simpler to interface directly to the third party themselves.

I believe this illustrates that, from a consumer of the monolithic message perspective, that it is important that developers of the consuming code *not* know what is happening under the covers.  If the designers had considered that the consumers of the monolithic message *should not* have to understand the abstraction in great detail, the monolithic message and it's associated name/value pairs might never have happened.  Documenting the abstraction with assertions regarding input and expected output would make life so much simpler.

As for colleges not teaching C and Lisp....they are cheating the students.  You get a better understanding of what is going on with the machine and OS with C.  You get a bit of a different perspective on processing data and approaching problems with Lisp.  I have used some of the ideas I learned using Lisp in programs written in C, C++, .Net, and Java.  Learning Java after knowing even just C is not very difficult.  The OO part is really not programming language specific, so perhaps using Java for that is acceptable.

Comment: HAHA the company wasn't TicketsNow, was it? :P

Answer (score 0):

An understanding of fundamentals of algorithms (e.g. time complexity) and some knowledge about the metal is essential to designing/writing smells-good code.

I would suggest, though, that just as important is education in modern abstractions and profiling. I feel that modern abstractions make me *so* much more productive than I would be without them that they are at least as important as good fundamentals, if not more so.

An important element that lacked in my education was the use of profilers. When used routinely and correctly, profilers can help mitigate problems with poor fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Since you quote Joel Spolsky, I take it your aware of his "Law of Leaky Abstractions"?  I'll mention it for future readers.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Green & Blackwell's *Ironies of Abstractions* talks a bit about the effort of learning the abstraction.  http://homepage.ntlworld.com/greenery/workStuff/Papers/index.html

The term "astronaut architecture" is a reaction to over-abstraction.

I know I certainly curse abstraction when I haven't touched Java or C# in a while and i want to write to a file, but have to instance a Stream...Writer...Adaptor....Handler....

Also, Patterns, as in Gang Of Four.  Seemed great when I first read about them in the mid-90's, but can never remember factory, facade, interface, helper, worker, flyweight....